# Training a regression model using Monai Densenet264 and MeanSquaredError Loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, regression

I am trying to add a MeanSquaredError Loss to a Densenet architecture retreived from monai (https://docs.monai.io/en/stable/networks.html#monai.networks.nets.DenseNet264) with the goal of training a regression model to output continous values from 0 to 4.

My approach was defining the network this way:

```py
model = DenseNet264(spatial_dims = 2, in_channels = 1, out_channels = 1, pretrained = False)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
```

And then doing normal training routine.

My input is a 2D image and my output should be a continuous value from 0 to 4

Is there something that I am missing?